# Minimize Cumulative Cost on Topological Sort

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, topological-sorting

We are given a n-vertex DAG $G=(V,E)$ and also given a cost function $c: V \rightarrow \Bbb N$.

Given a topological sort $S = v_1,v_2,...,v_n$, it has associated a sorting cost $S_c = \sum_{i=1}^{n} C(v_i)$
where $C(v_i)$ is the cost of choosing $v_i$ at that point: i.e. the sum of the cost functions of all vertices that were candidates at the point of choosing $v_i$, but they weren't chosen. Obviously, precedent vertices to $v_i$ in $S$ (already chosen vertices) are not included in this sum.

The idea is to find a topological sort $S$ that minimizes $S_c$. I think its a NP-hard problem, but would there be any approximation algorithm, or at least some smart heuristic? I tried to find this exact same problem but I couldn't find it... just similar ones.

Comment: What makes a given vertex $v$ a "candidate" at a given location $i$?  Any vertex that is not yet chosen?  Or maybe any vertex such that there is a topological order with the preceding $i-1$ vertices where they are, and that vertex $v$ in position $i$?  (These are not the same.)

Comment: Scheduling/ordering a DAG (representing unit time jobs) on a single machine to minimize weighted completion time is NP-Hard. Here each vertex has a weight $w(v)$ and $C(v_i) = w(v_i) \cdot i$ since $i$ is the completion time of job at position $i$.

Comment: I see. (Equivalently $C(v_i)$ is the sum over the vertices $v$ not yet chosen of $c(v_i)$.)  Is this *single machine scheduling with precedence constraints*?  [That problem seems to be NP hard but 2-approximable in polytime.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Single+Machine+Scheduling+with+Precedence+Constraints&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the 2-approximation for the scheduling problem. I worked on it in grad school :). 2 is the best one can get under UGC like assumptions, and that is a nice result due to Bansal and Khot. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5438609

Comment: A "candidate" is a vertex not yet chosen that has all its incoming vertices already in the sort at that point. So, it would be your second option. Other not-yet chosen vertex may not be a candidate because there are still other vertices that need to go first (dependency constraint)

Comment: So its not exactly the same problem youre describing (which i think is easier to model) because here you dont start counting the cost of some vertices from the start, just when its feasible to chose them.

Comment: Your objective is not very "natural" if the cost itself depends on the evolving schedule. What is the motivation?